# How to calculate date in kotlin with the given format?

Tags: kotlin

How to see if a user can be unbanned or not between 2 dates?

Hi, I have a given variable which is the date the user was unbanned as `end_banned` in the format `HH:mm:ss dd/MM/YYYY`.

`val end_banned: String= "15:05:00 12/01/2022"`

I want to calculate if at the current time they can be unbanned or not. I have tried with `SimpleDateFormat, Calendar, Date...` but still haven't found a solution.

1. I've tried separating each element of `seconds, minutes, days...` and comparing them with if...else like this:

```
var cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh")

var _hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)
var _minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
var _seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)
var _day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
var _month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1
var _year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)

var hours = end_banned.toString().substring(0, 2).toInt()
var minutes = end_banned.toString().substring(3, 5).toInt()
var seconds = end_banned.toString().substring(6, 8).toInt()
var day = end_banned.toString().substring(9, 11).toInt()
var month = end_banned.toString().substring(12, 14).toInt()
var year = end_banned.toString().substring(15).toInt()

if (_year >= year && _month >= month && _day >= day && _hours >= hours && _minutes >= minutes && _seconds >= seconds
    || _year >= year && _month >= month && _day >= day && _hours >= hours && _minutes >= minutes
    || _year >= year && _month >= month && _day >= day && _hours >= hours

    || _year >= year && _month >= month && _day >= day
    || _year >= year && _month >= month
    || _year >= year) {
    println("True")
} else {
    println("False")
}
```

But it is only true for the first 3 conditions when there are hours, minutes and seconds.

2. I tried with SimpleDateFormat and Date like this:

```
var cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh")

var hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)
var minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
var seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)
var day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
var month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1
var year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)

var sdf = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy")
var sdf_unbanned = sdf.parse(end_banned)
var sdf_now = sdf.parse("${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds} ${day}/${month}/${year}")

if (sdf_now.time - sdf_unbanned.time <= 0) {
     println(true)
} else {
     println(false)
}
```

But this condition always gives an incorrect number if I adjust the now and unbanned variables a few minutes apart (This makes it easier to spot)

Comment: `I have tried` please show your efforts

Comment: Please wait a moment, I'm only left with a bit of code that compares with if...else

Comment: I have edited my post again, there are many other things that I have tried since yesterday like: `compareTo()`, `after()`, `before()`...

Comment: On a side note, `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar`, and `Date` are all outdated. Prefer the `java.time` APIs (or Kotlin libraries like Kotlinx Datetime)

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand your question Sir, But I assume you want to compare unbanned_date to the current date (now time) if they are the same(we reached the unban date) then it should unban whatever you are unbanning, If so the implementation requires less code to achieve that ,Like this :

```
 val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        val strDate: Date = sdf.parse(end_banned)
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > strDate.getTime()) {
            urbanUser = true // or what ever your logic is 
        }
```

Comment: I want to check the accuracy down to the second like the given format. Maybe?

Comment: Well, Sir, I need to understand your full intent here, I know you want to unban something I got your goal idea but what is your intent by checking the accuracy down?

Comment: You are partly correct in the answer above. I want to check more if the hour, minute, second has not been reached, the user has not been unbanned and vice versa. Not just checking the date

Comment: Sir maybe my code is confusing and hard to understand, if the condition is true the user will get unbanned if it is false the user will remain banned, I assume you want to know the time left correct?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found the solution to my question. Have a nice day ^

Comment: Share the solution if you don't mind maybe someone will run into the same problem, Enjoy your day

Answer (score 0):

Shame, I got confused between `cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)` and `cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`

Because `cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)` returns only 12h format
And `cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` will return 24h format

I found a workaround and here is the code that I fixed and tested:

```
var cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh")
var sdf = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy")

var hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
var minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
var second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)
var day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
var month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1
var year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
var now: Date? = sdf.parse("${hour}:${minute}:${second} ${day}/${month}/${year}")
var end: Date? = sdf.parse(end_banned)

return now?.time!! > end?.time!!
```

Thanks for the help.